# Plots not showing up in R html document

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've written some simple code to plot some data, but for some reason I can't get it to print out on the html document when I knit it?

```r
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point()
```

I expect to see an image in the output, but instead, I just see the html code for one...

```
'''r
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point()
'''

<img src="hw5_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-3-1.png" width="672" />
```

Is there any reason why this would be happening? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and R 3.4.4

### Edit:

My entire markdown file for this looks like this:

```
---
title: DS Homework
author: Aaron
date: 4/10/2020
output: html_document
---

1. Question 1:
  a. Some part a
  b. Some part b

    '''{r}
    library(datasets)
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point()
    '''
2. Question 2:
```

Comment: The top yaml might affect it. Can you include that? It would help if you provide a "complete" Rmd document in your question. Thanks.

Comment: sure sure, just a sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot` works well in "interactive" mode however when you are sourcing your code you need to explicitly call `print()`. Thus either

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
print(ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point())
```

or

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point()
print(p)
```

Should work

Hope it helps

Comment: Exactly, as it is in the reference: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/print.ggplot.html

Comment: @iggy12345 I'm not sure about the whole update to R3.6+. It seems that explicit calls to print() for ggplot objects are independent of the R version . Could it be possible that you have updated any other package that changes the behavior of RMarkdown?

Comment: @davidnortes Okay, I actually figured it out this time

The questions in my Rmd file are part of a list, so instinctively, I indented my code blocks to make them line up nicely with the questions, well, that makes the output print verbatim, and not as a graph.

Answer (score 2):

I've since figured out that in fact, it was actually, because I was indenting the code blocks, unindenting the code blocks fixed the issue

```
1. Question 1:
  a. Some part a
  b. Some part b

    '''{r}
    library(datasets)
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point()
    '''

2. Question 2:
```

to

```
1. Question 1:
  a. Some part a
  b. Some part b

'''{r}
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight)) + geom_point()
'''

2. Question 2:
```

Comment: You can still indent the code blocks, I do that all the time. While it's probable you're using single-quotes here because you don't know how to do embedded backticks on SO, in case that's not the case ... single-quotes aren't correct, indented or otherwise. (I'm guessing you really have backticks ...)

Comment: I am using single quotes because I don't know how to use embedded back-ticks

Answer (score 0):

put `print()` before the ggplot or any other plotting line

e.g

from

```
surface3d(wt1, hp1,pred, alpha=.2)
```

to

```
print(surface3d(wt1, hp1,pred, alpha=.2))
```

Alternatively you can these in the code chunk if you are using  rgl library

```
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
setupKnitr(autoprint=TRUE)
```

E.g.

````
\\```{r}
library(rgl)
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
setupKnitr(autoprint=TRUE)
\\```
````